# Calling Method from another class returns Null

Tags: class, button, methods, view

I have a xml that has button that has the onClick attribute:

`<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnSample1"
        android:text="Sample1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtView"
        />`

at my MainActivity, I have given it a listener that would call a method from another class

```
` View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            AnotherClass me = new AnotherClass();
            me.receive(v);

        }
    };

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSample1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(listener);
}`
```

but this returns me a NullPointerException error.

this is my code for the AnotherClass class:

```
public class AnotherClass extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context x;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.anotherClasslayout);

    }

    public AnotherClass() {

        View v = new View(x);
        receive(v);

    }

    public void receive(View view){

//some code

}
```

I couldn't make this work, is there any thing I can do to call and execute a method from another class that needs view parameter